# Why doesn't such a file or directory, <cblas.h>, exist?

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication

I am doing some matrix multiplication in C and I am trying to compile my progam however it fails to compile for the reason:

> No such file or directory cblas.h

This is the command I am using to compile:

```
gcc -o BLAS BLAS.c
```

Can anybody please help me? I am compiling this program on a server. I'm not sure if this makes a difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a `-I directory` option where `directory` is the place where the `cblas.h` file is located on your system.

This gives:

```
gcc -o BLAS -I directory_of_cblas_header BLAS.c
```

Comment: So I'm not sure where my headers are on my system. From the server is it "~/usr/lib/libblas" ? Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: run `find / -name cblas.h`, it should point out where the file `cblas.h` on your system.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a path to the header files of the library you are using. Try it with the `-I` option:

```
gcc -o -I "path/to/you/headers" BLAS BLAS.c
```

Comment: I'm not sure where the header is stored or if I even have it. I have tried compiling like this gcc -o -I /usr/lib/libblas/ BLAS BLAS.c thanks for the answer so far.

Answer (score -2):

I'm using RedHat7.

After install openblas by `sudo yum install openblas-devel`

I find that the header files (cblas.h, f77blas.h, lapacke_config.h, lapacke.h, lapacke_mangling.h, lapacke_utils.h, openblas_config.h) are in `/usr/include/openblas/`.

By creating soft links to these files in `/usr/include/`, the problem is solved.

Comment: That is an extremely wrong 'solution'. The subdirectory is by design. Libraries are supposed to put their headers in separate subdirectories of `/usr/include`. So you either `#include <openblas/whatever.h>` or pass your preprocessor an `-I` flag or equivalent to tell it also to search in `/usr/include/openblas`. You don't start symlinking things in the root of `include`.