# Word Embedding Compression by Binarization (Tissier) // C-Binaries

Tags: c, word-embedding

For my bachelor thesis I want to apply this algorithm proposed here: [Binarization by Tissier](https://github.com/tca19/near-lossless-binarization)

I cloned the repository and tried to run `cd near-lossless-binarization` in the corrsponding directory.

However there comes up an error I don't know how to solve.

```
 cd near-lossless-binarization && make
gcc binarize.c -o binarize -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Ofast -funroll-loops -lblas -lm 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccxe5d0J.o: in function `apply_regularizarion_gradient':
binarize.c:(.text+0xddc): undefined reference to `cblas_sgemm'
/usr/bin/ld: binarize.c:(.text+0xf9e): undefined reference to `cblas_sgemm'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccxe5d0J.o: in function `apply_reconstruction_gradient':
binarize.c:(.text+0x1059): undefined reference to `cblas_sgemm'
/usr/bin/ld: binarize.c:(.text+0x12fb): undefined reference to `cblas_sgemm'
/usr/bin/ld: binarize.c:(.text+0x1800): undefined reference to `cblas_sgemm'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccxe5d0J.o:binarize.c:(.text+0x1e71): more undefined references to `cblas_sgemm' follow
collect2: Error: ld gab 1 as end-Status returned
```

Seems like there is an issue inside the corresponding file.

I already opened an issue in the repo, but need answers pretty soon..

Hoped to find anyone with C experience here who may solve my problem.

Requirements named in the repo are fulfilled.

Comment: You should ask the repo maintainer.

Comment: These may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7874350/6865932 or https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3599 it appears you are missing a library.